# BSon Exception newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json.net

Given 

        `public class Something
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ver")]
            public string ver { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SomethingElse")]
            public object somethingElse { get; set; } // will blow up 
            // public SomethingElse somethingElse { get; set; } // will not
        }
        public class SomethingElse
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "uuid")]
            public Guid uuid { get; set; }
        }`

Attempting to serialize then deserialize Something will throw Unable cast object of type Guid to Byte[] exception if the member somethingelse of something is an object rather than the type itself.

Sorry for the lack of details. Above was a simplified class that you can serialize but cannot deserialize the object. Below matches are situation more closely, only difference is the dictionary we need is , that will fail as well in the exact same manner. The example works with JSOn, not BSON. The serialization appears valid, just the deserialization throws an exception in the JSonWriter Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Byte[]',line 552

```
case JsonToken.Bytes:

WriteValue((byte[])reader.Value);<-- is trying to case a Guid to byte array
```

break;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           const string path = @"C:\zzz_bson.dat";
           WriteBson(path);
           ReadBson(path);
    }

    private static void ReadBson(string path)
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var file = File.OpenRead(path);
        var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file);
        var bsonReader = new BsonReader(binaryReader);
        var something = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(bsonReader); 
        file.Close();
    }

    private static void WriteBson(string path)
    {
        //var something = new Dictionary<string, Guid> { { "uuid", new Guid("8afbc8b8-5449-4c70-abd4-3e07046d0f61") } };  //fails
        var something = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "uuid", new Guid("8afbc8b8-5449-4c70-abd4-3e07046d0f61").ToString() } }; // works
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var file = File.OpenWrite(path);
        var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(file);
        var bsonWriter = new BsonWriter(binaryWriter);
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, something);
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: So you're surprised it wants its properties explicitly typed here? Is that a problem - do you need to accept any old object here?

Comment: Your intentionally vague code sample won't help us help you. Do you have a sample of the json? What about the actual class definition?